# dig -x www.google.com

Tags: dns, dig

I'm trying to learn more about the dig command and have come across the `-x` option which is meant for reverse lookup, i.e. you give an IP address and get back a domain name.

I tried doing `dig -x www.google.com` which I guess doesn't really make sense with the `-x` option, but I got back this response:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-29.el7_2.3 <<>> -x www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 2959
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;com.google.www.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
in-addr.arpa.       3180    IN  SOA b.in-addr-servers.arpa. nstld.iana.org. 2015074802 1800 900 604800 3600

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 128.114.142.6#53(128.114.142.6)
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 16 17:06:24 PDT 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```

Can anybody help me get a better understanding of what this reponse tells us, I thought you weren't supposed to use the `-x` option with a domain name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice in the response that you got back `status: NXDOMAIN` and `ANSWER: 0`. This means there was no record found matching your query.

The `-x` option to `dig` is merely a convenience for constructing a `PTR` query. It splits on dots, reverses it, appends `in-addr.arpa.`, and sets the type to `PTR`.

The information you did get back is the SOA record for the authoritative domain (`in-addr.arpa`), and is for result caching. Negative lookups (queries which have no results) can be cached for a duration as specified in the SOA record.

See [RFC-2308](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308#section-3):

> Name servers authoritative for a zone MUST include the SOA record of
> the zone in the authority section of the response when reporting an
> NXDOMAIN or indicating that no data of the requested type exists.
> This is required so that the response may be cached.  The TTL of this
> record is set from the minimum of the MINIMUM field of the SOA record
> and the TTL of the SOA itself, and indicates how long a resolver may
> cache the negative answer.

Answer (score 2):

It does not return an address record. The DNS request fails successfully. The `-x` wants an IP address to prepend to `.in-addr.arpa`.